# how to create pdf reports from php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to create a report from details of guest table. but it gives following error.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/a5899527/public_html/cpanel/testrep2.php on line 17**

```
<?php
include("connect.php");


$SQL="SELECT * FROM guest ";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($run);

require('/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
}
foreach($row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

please give a solution?  **Line 17 is foreach($row) {**

Comment: missing semicolon after `$row=mysql_fetch_array($run)` obviously

Comment: You just forgot the terminating semicolon (`;`) in the line before: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($run)`.

Comment: Incidentally, that line of code would normally appear inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

put `;` here `$row=mysql_fetch_array($run)`

```
foreach($row) { // here you didn't use 'as' 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($row as $column)
    $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
```

change your code like this.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($row as $column)
 $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
```

Comment: now it gives a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/a5899527/public_html/cpanel/testrep2.php on line 17  --------- foreach($row) {-----------------------------

Comment: That's a different question. Also, don't use PHP's mysql_ API